# Cut'n'paste between X11 Desktop and the virt-manager VNC graphical console of a Win7 VM guest on a Server

Tags: windows-7, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, vdi

I have a licensed copy of MicroSoft **Windows 7** professional installed and running as guest on my Linux server running **qemu-kvm**.  This works just fine.

But I was unable to figure out how to **Cut'n'paste** text selections from a window of the Win7 VM into X11 or vice versa.

Is this possible?  How?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not yet supported.

When necessary, I work around it by connecting to the Windows VM via RDP (in my case using Remmina, but you can use whatever you like).

Comment: RDP is the best option; plus it will be more responsive as most of the graphics (including the mouse cursor) will be rendered by your RDP client rather than the VM.

Answer (score 1):

VNC has no facility for clipboard passthrough. You might want to try spice, with the proper agents it works quite well.